# What is the difference between Shimano 14-28T MF-TZ20 and Shimano MF-TZ500-6?

Tags: shimano, cassette, tourney

What is the difference between Shimano 14-28T MF-TZ20 and Shimano MF-TZ500-6 ?

[Shimano MF-TZ500-6, Shimano website](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/tourney/MF-TZ500-6.html)

[Shimano 14-28T MF-TZ20, Ebay shop](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Shimano-Cassette-14-28T-MF-TZ20-6S-Speed-MTB-Road-Cycling-Bike-Bicycle-Freewheel/362723452079?)

Does it mean that "Shimano 14-28T MF-TZ20" (which doesn't appear on shimano website) is **fake**?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just saw on an ebay listing that the TZ500 replaced the TZ20.

Answer (score 1):

They're both freewheels, so likely the design has been around for decades.  At this price point in the market, noone really compares features, a user is more interested in specs like max/min toothcount and number of cogs.  Thats about it.

Specs are identical - they're both 6 speed with 14 tooth minimum and 28 tooth maximum cogs.

The TZ20 is probably a later version, possibly made in a different way to reduce manufacturing costs.  Notice t that the TZ500 has a black large cog, where the TZ20 has the same colour cogs all the way through.

Minor difference is that the TZ20 pictured has a black plastic spoke protector included in the picture, whereas the TZ500 does not show one.

---

As for being fake, that's always possible given the age of these designs.  But there's also minimal profit in these low-end low-value items, and realistically even a fake one should work fine.

Comment: if the TZ20 is a later version, why it doesn't appear on Shimano website?

Comment: @MichaelD that's a question for shimano.     I found https://bike.shimano.com/ko-KR/product/component/tourney/MF-TZ21.html as a korean TZ21, and I also see TZ20 listed in this https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-6NVRA-004-ENG.pdf   so it definitely exists/existed.   Perhaps even Shimano don't really care much about Tourney contrasted with groupsets at the high end like DuraAce.

Comment: Thank you @Criggie! Somehow, I would expect more from a respectful manufacturer, even for a basic line.